# Redirect www.example.com/folder to folder.example.com

Tags: apache-2.2, subdomain

I have a url that looks like this: **www.example.com/folder**. Now, I was wondering how I can tell Apache to redirect the url to **folder.example.com**

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: @quanta Okay thanks. But maybe the word I should have used was Redirect

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution is to place a single  `.htaccess` file inside your `/folder` directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example\.com [NC]
  RewriteRule (.*) http://folder.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

Please note, that your Apache needs to be configured with [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)